# MATLAB: Using lsim to High Pass Filter a wavread audio file

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB.  Our Assignment was to create a HPF using the tf command where the filter is 
H=tf([tau, 0],[tau , 1]);.
And to use this HPF on an audio file, which I imported  using the command 
[x, Fs] = wavread('StringMono.wav');
and I am trying to use the lsim command to find the result of the HPF on the audio file.
y= lsim(H,x,t);
After executing my Matlab code I keep getting the error message that the input
data U must be a matrix with as many rows as samples in the time
vector T, and as many columns as input channels.  I've been trying to figure out how to fix this problem for an hour now and can't find a solution. Does my t vector have to be something specific in order for this to work. I've tried a few different values for t with no avail.  Addition Info: fc=100Hz, Tau=1/wc.  Any Input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

t needs to be an array for time so that the input matrix knows when to provide a new input. Since Fs is provided, the equation is simple:

```
t = (0:Fs:(size(x,1)*Fs - Fs));
```